# How do I convert the update.img artifact from the Orange Pi 4 LTS Android build to an image I can flash on a microSD card?

Tags: android, android-source, sd-card, orange-pi

I have successfully built Android 8.1 from the [sources provided for the Orange Pi 4 LTS](http://www.orangepi.org/html/hardWare/computerAndMicrocontrollers/service-and-support/Orange-pi-4-LTS.html). According to the Orange Pi 4 LTS User Manual (downloaded from the previous link)--on the final page 399--"…update.img is the Android firmware that can be burned and run". But when I follow the instructions in the [Orange Pi 4 wiki page](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepiwiki/index.php/Orange_Pi_4) to [burn Android firmware to TF card](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepiwiki/index.php/Orange_Pi_4_LTS#How_to_burn_Android_firmware_to_TF_card), it won't boot.

I can successfully boot from a microSD card when I use the Android 8.1 image I downloaded from [www.orangepi.org](http://www.orangepi.org/html/hardWare/computerAndMicrocontrollers/service-and-support/Orange-pi-4-LTS.html). But the Android 12 image I download doesn't work--not surprisingly since that download is not in a folder named "Image boot from SD card" like the 8.1 image.

So it appears whatever was done to convert the Android 8.1 image to one that will boot from an SD card would need to be done to the Android 12 image or my `update.img` file.

Comment: Be aware of the social media links at the bottom of: http://www.orangepi.org/html/hardWare/computerAndMicrocontrollers/service-and-support/Orange-pi-4-LTS.html which may provide assistive resources.